# Expandable Nested Boxes with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, nesting

Could someone please post a minimal `tikz` example to draw this:

[image: nested boxes with tikz]

I am currently doing this with nested tables, but would like to see how it can be done with tikz.

The nodes would ideally have a pre-set minimal width and height, yet expand with their contents.

Comment: "The nodes would ideally have a pre-set minimal width and height, yet expand with their contents." That is the standard behaviour of nodes, isn't it?

Comment: @Seamus: Normally the minimal width and height is zero IIRC. The expanding part is standard behaviour.

Comment: @Martin right, but `minimum height` and `minimum width` are keys tikz recognises...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `shapes.multipart` library of `TikZ` can be helpful (refer to Section 48.6
*Shapes with Multiple Text Parts* of the pgfmanual); a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  double/.style={draw, anchor=text, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2},
  triple/.style={draw, anchor=text, rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3}
  ]
  \node[triple] {foo
    \nodepart{second}
      bar
    \nodepart{third}
      \tikz{\node[double] {\nodepart{second}baz};}
  };

  \node[triple] at (2.2,0) {some text here
    \nodepart{second}
      bar
    \nodepart{third}
      \tikz{\node[double] {\nodepart{second}some more text goes here};}
  };

  \node[double,align=center] at (7.5,0) {some text here
    \nodepart{second}
      bar \\
      \tikz{\node[double,align=center] {\nodepart{second}some more text\\ goes here};}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely, thank you! How would I go about breaking text though? `some more \\ text goes here` just removes the space between `more` and `text`.

Comment: @Nickolay Kolev: you can use the `align=` key for the nodes; I've updated my example.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know about the [`drs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/drs) package? (I assuming you want to construct discourse representation structures and `tikz` itself isn't a requirement.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{drs}
\begin{document}
\drs{X}{ the lawyers(X) \\ 
   \qdrs{x}{x $\in$ X}
        {every}{x} 
        {y}{secretary(y) \\ x hired y}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do know it, and it is what I am using right now. I am having a few issues with it though, and I wanted to learn TikZ anyway, so I thought of writing a replacement.