# Aligning nodes with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, nodes

Consider this:

[image: misaligned nodes]

There are several problems:

1. The `\exists` operator is not horizontaly aligned with the following node (a,b).
2. There is too little space between `foobar` and the node below it and between the (a,b) node and the nodes below it.
3. The right arrow is not horizontally aligned with the preceding and following nodes. (I know that I can draw arrows with TikZ, this is just a placeholder.)

Any help on resolving these issues is greatly appreciated. Here is the code at present.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=3mm and 3mm,
  drs/.style={draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}
  ]
  \node[drs,align=left]
    { foo
      \nodepart{two}

        foobar \
        \tikz{
          \node (operator) {$\exists$};
          \node[drs,right=of operator]{
            a%
            \nodepart{two}{
              b%
            }
          };
        } \
        \tikz{
          \node[drs] (left side)
            { 1%
              \nodepart{two}
                2%
            };
          \node[right=of left side] (operator) {$\rightarrow$};
          \node[drs,right=of operator] (right side)
            { 3%
              \nodepart{two}
                4 \\
                5 \\
                6%
            };
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: By "horizontally aligned", do you mean you want their centers to be on the same *height* (i.e. *vertical position*)?

Comment: see my answer to your other question [Expandable nested boxed with tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18600/expandable-nested-boxes-with-tikz) if you are interested in drawing DRS's independent of `tikz`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problems 1) and 3): you can control the alignment using the `mid` anchor of nodes. Problem 2): you can use the optional argument of the line changing command `\\`; here's a modified version of your code, feel free to change the lengths according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  drs/.style={draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}
  ]
  \node[drs,align=left]
    { foo
      \nodepart{two}
        foobar \\[.5em]
        \tikz{
          \node (operator) {$\exists$};
          \node[drs,right=2mm of operator.mid]{
            a%
            \nodepart{two}{
              b%
            }
          };
        } \\[.5em]
        \tikz{
          \node (operator) {$\rightarrow$};
          \node[drs,left=4mm of operator.mid] (left side)
            { 1%
              \nodepart{two}
                2%
            };
          \node[drs,right=4mm of operator.mid] (right side)
            { 3%
              \nodepart{two}
                4 \\
                5 \\
               6%
            };
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]