# Using tikz command inside tikzpicture environment (alignment problem)

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

This is a followup question to [Expandable nested boxes with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18600/expandable-nested-boxes-with-tikz).

When using the `\tikz` command inside the `tikzpicture` environment, the positioning of the contents is altered.

Here are the two examples:

[image]

And the code responsible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

Here we have a
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
  \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] at (0,0)
    { foo%
      \nodepart{two}
        bar
    };
\end{tikzpicture} picture.

Here we have a
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
  \tikz{
    \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] at (0,0)
      { foo%
        \nodepart{two}
          bar
      };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
picture.

\end{document}
```

The lower left corner of the node in the second example is just right in the middle of the picture, so there must be a very good reason it is there. :-) Which one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `\tikz` inside a `tikzpicture` environment like this. I have no idea what you are trying to do or what makes you think you can do this.

The `\tikz` command is the short version of the `tikzpicture` environment. Having it direct inside a `tikzpicture` environment makes as much sense as using a `tikzpicture` environment inside a `tikzpicture` environment!

So you second picture is basically:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] at (0,0)
      { foo%
        \nodepart{two}
          bar
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Still wondering why this doesn't get you good results?

The only surprise here is that both doesn't raise an error message! (This should be sent as bug report to the developers.)

You can't safely use arbitrary normal typesetting commands inside a `tikzpicture`. It's whole content is placed into a dummy TeX box which is later discarded while the drawing commands add their material into a second box which is typeset afterwards. Try adding some text without anything else into the picture. TikZ will just ignore it. You can however safely use `\tikz` or `tikzpicture` inside the content of a node. TikZ takes care to interrupt the current picture while processing the node content.

I could now speculate why you get exactly the output you get, but this would matter much. Apparently the size/bounding box survives but the placement is of.

---

If you want to be able to use drawing code inside and outside a node you can see if you are currently inside a `tikzpicture` by testing of e.g. `\path` has its normal TikZ definition. Note that TikZ reverts its own commands to the previous definition when typesetting the contents of nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes.multipart}

\makeatletter
% Ensures processing of content inside a `tikzpicture` (using the short version `\tikz`)
\newcommand{\ensuretikz}{%
  \ifx\path\tikz@command@path
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\tikz
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here we have a
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
  \node {
  \ensuretikz{%
  \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] at (0,0)
    { foo%
      \nodepart{two}
        bar
    };
 }
 };
\end{tikzpicture} picture.

Here we have a
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
  \ensuretikz{
    \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] at (0,0)
      { foo%
        \nodepart{two}
          bar
      };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
picture.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to define a new command which draws a node (say rectangle) and add the `\tikz` command if it is called inside the content of another node?

Comment: @Nickolay: I updated my answer to include a possible solution. You should have stated this in the question from the beginning so that people know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know that it sounds odd to have a `\tikz` command inside a `tikzpicture` environment but, under some circumstances it can be helpful and I really liked this when I noticed that it could be done. I don't see this as a bug, but as a feature.

Comment: @Gonzalo: It doesn't seem to work reliable. I would use a `scope` or `\node {\tikz{...}};` instead.

Comment: ah, yes... I meant using `\tikz` as the argument of `\node` (as I suggested in some other answer here); I didn't read carefully this question, so I initially didn't realize that Nickolay was using `\tikz` "directly" inside `\tikzpicture`, which, in fact, doesn't seem the right thing to do. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @MartinScharrer `\ensuretikz` is very interesting, you can look at this question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46596/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-tikzpicture  for another possibility. I encounter  only one problem with nested tikzpicture environments but it's a next question.

Answer (score 3):

I find this question before asking  [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture)

I don't understand why a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture is a wrong thing, I understand that it's perhaps strange or very strange but there are some examples of linked environments.

I realize with the pgfornament package that it's possible but we need to be careful. Till Tantau thought about this with `\tikzifinpicture` (see the question 
[how to check ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46596/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-tikzpicture)  Ok it's perhaps a wrong idea but it works  despite the Tantau'comment

> % TT: This is a wrong  test! Who uses this?...

Now the problem is simple : You are inside a tikz's  picture and you create a new picture (tikz or not tikz). This picture is placed at the current point, here the center of the rectangle, and by default the picture is placed with the south west anchor like in this case :

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes.multipart}
    \begin{document}

Here we have \tikz{%
    \node[draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]  at (0,0)
      { foo%
        \nodepart{two}
          bar
      }; 
        } and  \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]{
    \node[anchor=west,draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]  at (0,0)
      { foo%
        \nodepart{two}
          bar
      }; 
        } picture.  

    \end{document}
```

In your case you need to do the same thing :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

Here we have a   
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
    \tikz[baseline=(x.center)]{
    \node[anchor=west,draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] (x) at (0,0)
      { foo%
        \nodepart{two}
          bar
      };
  }% 
\end{tikzpicture}
picture.  

\end{document}
```