# Alignment of node "groups" in TikZ using `\matrix` or other constructs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to align 2 groups of TikZ nodes but cannot figure out how to do this.  I tried wrapping each group with `\tikz{...}` but that didn't work (probably because of [\tikz inside tikzpicture environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18647/using-tikz-command-inside-tikzpicture-environment-alignment-problem).  Currently, I am using `\matrix` but it aligns the nodes horizontally at the left (and I would like center) and doesn't use equal spacing between lines (or maybe, it does, but I would like it to change to a minimum spacing?)

Anyway, I have a feeling that my goal could be accomplished with `\matrix` but I am open to other approaches to group nodes, too.  For example, I haven't fully understood the `{scope}` environment.

Here is my MWE illustrating the problem (I'd be also happy to hear if the MWE could be made more minimal, i.e., my tikz coding could be improved):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

% some style definitions:
\newcommand\scriptsize{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\selectfont} % because of 'minimal' documentclass
% settings for lexemes
\tikzset{font=\scriptsize}
\tikzset{mynode/.style = {rectangle,minimum width=#1,draw=black!70}}
\tikzset{mynode/.default = 2mm}
% macro for drawing multiple lexemes next to each other:
\newcommand{\lexemes}[1]{%
    \node (A) [mynode] {};
    \xdef\lastx{A}
    \foreach \x/\lbl/\d in {#1} {
      \node (\x) [mynode,label=center:\lbl,right=\d of \lastx] {};
      \xdef\lastx{\x}  
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.08 and 0.05]
  \matrix [anchor=west] at (0,3) {%  no labels, so rows very tight
    \lexemes{C//} \\
    \lexemes{C//,D//2mm,F//} \\
  };
  \matrix [anchor=west] at (0,2) {%  label in upper row, so less tight
    \lexemes{B/1/,C//} \\
    \lexemes{C//,D//2mm,F//} \\
  };
  \matrix [anchor=west] at (0,1) {%  labels in both rows, so this should be the constant row sep?
    \lexemes{B/1/,C//} \\
    \lexemes{B/3/,C//,D//2mm,F//} \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

Now I would like to accomplish 2 things:

1. Center the first and second row of each pair/matrix.
2. Have an equal vertical separation between the first and second row of each matrix independent of the node label used.  I would measure between the edges of the rectangles.

Comment: I believe your code could be made more minimal by removing all the complicated instructions and producing a simplistic (i.e. boring and ugly) picture where the *only* thing in question is node alignment.  In particular, I don't believe your new shape is relevant to the question (replace it with some oddly-sized standard shape), and neither are your styles.

Comment: By the way, about `scope`: its purpose is to locally set TikZ options.  That's it.  So for example, you could have a `scope` setting, say, `shift = {(1,0)}` to move everything right one unit, but it is (I think) much harder to arrange purely through options that the *center* of a scope is at a particular place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, now I understand your problem.  Here are the fixes:

1. To get the rows centered, place them in `\node`s with anchors at their center.  A `\matrix` aligns its columns by their "origin", which is rather tricky to change for complex constructions, but for a node is always where the anchor is.
2. To get the spacing right, you have to make sure the `inner sep` of your labels is zero; each `label` is a new node, and as it turns out, its invisible extent is somewhat larger than the box you drew it in.

The `\node` in point 1 also has an `inner sep`, which I have to set to zero to avoid putting big spaces between *every* row.  As it turns out, your style sets only `minimum width` and relies on `inner sep` to force the height, so to prevent the boxes from flattening out when they are contained in a scope with `inner sep = 0`, I have changed `minimum width=#1` to `minimum size=#1`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,matrix}

% some style definitions:
\newcommand\scriptsize{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\selectfont} % because of 'minimal' documentclass
% settings for lexemes
\tikzset{font=\scriptsize}
% changed minimum width to minimum size
\tikzset{mynode/.style = {rectangle,minimum size=#1,draw=black!70}}
\tikzset{mynode/.default = 2mm}
% macro for drawing multiple lexemes next to each other:
\newcommand{\lexemes}[1]{%
 \node[anchor=center,inner sep=0pt]{
  \tikz{
   \node (A) [mynode] {};
   \xdef\lastx{A}
   \foreach \x/\lbl/\d in {#1} {
     \tikzset{every label/.style = {inner sep = 0}}
     \node (\x) [mynode,label=center:\lbl,right=\d of \lastx] {};
     \xdef\lastx{\x}  
   }
  }
 };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance=0.08 and 0.05,
]
  \matrix [anchor=west] at (0,3) {%  no spaces, so rows very tight
    \lexemes{C//} \\
    \lexemes{C//,D//2mm,F//} \\
  };
  \matrix [anchor=west] at (0,2) {%  space in upper row, so less tight
    \lexemes{B/1/,C//} \\
    \lexemes{C//,D//2mm,F//} \\
  };
  \matrix [anchor=west] at (0,1) {%  spaces in both rows, so this should be the constant row sep?
    \lexemes{B/1/,C//} \\
    \lexemes{B/3/,C//,D//2mm,F//} \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a great "minimal" answer.  I added `row sep=1mm` to the matrix options to get a little bit of space between the rows (I hadn't really specified this in my question).  Now that your answer makes the distance between rows equal the result is what I ultimately wanted.