# How can I check if the current code is inside a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I read the answer for this [question (inside a environment)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-certain-environment) but I would like to know if there is something more specific. LaTeX keeps the current environment in the macro `\@currenvir` but how do the test with the plain TEX format or the ConTEXt format.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TikZ has a command `\tikzifinpicture` that does the test:

```
\tikzifinpicture{true branch}{false branch}
```

However, the comments in the definition of the command (`tikz.code.tex`) say

```
% TT: This is a wrong
% test! Who uses this?...
```

So there may be a better way.

Comment: Thanks I imagined to test something but not ` \pgfutil@ifundefined{filldraw}`

Comment: I need to send a mail to TT : `TT: This is a wrong test! Who uses this?...`    me !

Comment: The macro works fairly well -- but not for nested pictures (i.e. it says "true" even if the current picture is temporarily interrupted).

Comment: I use it to render a PGF picture if tikzpicture environment is used to surround the picture. Then it skips the pgfpicture environment. If standalone the pgfpicture environment is used.