# TikZ: [baseline] interferes with blur shadow on background layer

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using `[baseline]` on a `tikzpicture` with a background layer seems to interfere with the placement of a blur shadow:

[image]

MWE (for use with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[text width=0.4\textwidth,inner xsep=4mm,inner ysep=2mm] (A){TEXT};
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \path[draw=black!30, blur shadow, fill=gray!10]
      (A.south east) -- (A.south west) -- (A.north west)  -- (A.north east) -- cycle ;%
   \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Deleting the `[baseline]` makes everything work fine, as does substituting `drop shadow` for `blur shadow`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in [`pgf-blur`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-blur).  Part of the construction of the drop shadow involves making a new picture and it is incorrectly inheriting the `baseline` options from the main picture.  I've pushed a revision to [TeX-SX Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files) which purports to fix this, but it will need testing (please do!) and it is for the package author to decide on how best to fix this before uploading to CTAN.

Comment: Running `latex` on pgf-blur.dtx (revision 169) gives 
>Package doc Error: Checksum not passed (456<>475).  (Presumably this is a cosmetic error.)

Comment: @Mohan Yes, at this stage the checksum is cosmetic.

Comment: @LoopSpace tested here, too, it fixes some more bugs, too. Did you try to contact the upstream author and see whether one can get a released fixed version?