# Drop shadow of baselined tikz node not placed correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, shadows

I want to draw a tikz node that has as its baseline the baseline of the text around *and* have a drop shadow. My code however causes the drop shadow to be misplaced.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\newcommand{\propbox}[1]{
    \hspace{-.125cm}\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]{\node[
      fill = red,
      blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}] (A) {#1};}
}


\begin{document}
This is \propbox{some} sample text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare this to the correct shadow, where the baseline for the node is not specified:

[image]

How can I fix the shadow?

Comment: Unrelated: instead of the `\hspace`, add a `%` at the end of the `\newcommand{\propbox}[1]{` line, to remove the space caused by the newline in the code.

Comment: Seems that an old bug has returned: [TikZ: baseline interferes with blur shadow on background layer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86287/4301)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a temporary hack that you can use:

[image]

### Note

- Are per Torbjørn T's suggestion, you can eliminate the `\hspace{-.125cm}` hack by inserting a `%` follwoing the open paren as that eliminates the suprious space that was being inserted.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}


\newcommand{\propbox}[1]{%
    %\hspace{-.125cm} <-- Hack fixed by % above
    \tikz[baseline=(A.base)]{
        \node[outer sep=1pt,
          fill = red,
          blur shadow={
              shadow blur steps=5,
              baseline=(A.south),% <--- ADDED
          },
        ] (A) {#1};%
    }% <--- NOTE. Without this you will have additional space following the `\propbox'
}


\begin{document}
This is \propbox{some} sample text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

using tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcommand{\propbox}[1]{
  \hspace{-.125cm}\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]{\node[
    fill = red,
    blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}] (A) {#1};}
}

\begin{document}

This is \propbox{some} sample text.

This is \tcbox[enhanced, size=fbox, drop fuzzy shadow=black, 
nobeforeafter, boxsep=2pt, coltext=white, frame hidden, on line,
colback=red!75,]{some} sample text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is there a solution with tikz? This was just a minimal working example and I have a lot of tikz stuff in my actual code. For example I have these boxes shaded in my actual code and I just spent 30 min trying to figure out how I can do that with this tcolobox thing.