# How to overwrite a node setting in Tikz to align Tikz pictures to nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting

A Tikz picture has four nodes and each node has a new tikz picture, an inheritance problem coming. I have four Tikz pictures where each is inside a node and each node has size of 4cm times 4cm (square) but this size is inherited to other nodes where node size only ~1mm as shown in Bad Demo below with big black circles. So

> **How can I overwrite Tikz node settings in the inner nodes?**

**Bad Demo** Four tikz pictures jammed together bad

> [image]

*Four tikz pictures with larger node but node style inherited, how to overwrite it?*

> [image]
>
> where my goal is to have each node of size 4cm and each single tikz picture inside each node -- by this I try to make my tikz pictures more accessible and visually pleasing.

*MWE*

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[minimum size=4cm](q1)[label=(a) $x_1+x_2$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\coordinate [label=$x_1$] (1) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=$x_2$] (2) at (1,0);
\node[draw=none,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] (11) at (1){};
\node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black] (22) at (2){};
\end{tikzpicture}
};


\node(q2)[right =of q1,label=(b) $x_1+x_1x_2+x_2x_3$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\coordinate [label=$x_1$] (1) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=$x_1x_2$] (2) at (1,0);
\coordinate [label=$x_2x_3$] (3) at (2,0);
\draw (1)--(2)--(3);
\node [circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (11) at (1){};
\node [circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (22) at (2){};
\node [circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt] (33) at (3){};
\end{tikzpicture}
};


\node(q3)[below =of q1,label=(c) $x_1x_2x_3+x_1+x_2+x_3$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\coordinate [label=left:$x_1$] (1) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:$x_2$] (2) at (2,0);
\coordinate [label=below:$x_3$] (3) at (1,-2);
\coordinate [label=right:$x_1x_2x_3$] (123) at (1,-1);
\draw (1)--(123)--(2);
\draw (3)--(123);
\end{tikzpicture}
};


\node(q4)[right =of q3,label=(d) $x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_2x_3$]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm, y=2cm]
\coordinate [label=left:$x_1$] (1) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:$x_2$] (2) at (2,0);
\coordinate [label=below:$x_3$] (3) at (1,-2);
\coordinate [label=right:$x_1x_2x_3$] (123) at (1,-0.8);
\draw (1)--(123)--(2)--(1);
\draw (3)--(123);
\draw (1)--(3);
\draw (3)--(2);
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where `[minimum size=4cm]` creates the two big circles, its removal returns the jammed pictures in the beginning.

**Trials**

> **Trial 1:** scope is suggested to avoid the overwriting but `LaTeX Error: Environment scope is undefined`, why?
>
> [image]

Comment: Don't use tikz picture inside tikz picture. Use scope instead. Don't use a scope inside a node but shift the scope to the node.

Comment: Don't nest TikZ pictures. It is expected to break as @Tarass indicates.

Comment: Those look as if they should be `subfigure`s or something rather than putting the captions within the pictures.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46818/what-are-most-important-variables-set-at-the-beginning-of-a-tikzpicture-of-a-sc, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node etc.

Comment: @Tarass can you clarify `Don't use a scope inside a node but shift the scope to the node.`? What does the latter mean? Trial 1 demonstrate the former, not suggested, how to overcome this?

Comment: You want `\begin{scope}[shift={(x,y)}] \node etc. \end{scope}`, not `\node at (x,y) {\begin{scope} this doesn't work \end{scope}};`