# Combine Tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to combine two tikz pictures that were created using separate environments?

Basically I have a macro create a backdrop that I will use often but I would like to create a layer on top of it which will change each time I use it so

```
\backdrop
\begin{tikzpicture}

\end {tikzpicture}
```

but have the tikzpicture use the same coordinate axis, scale, etc and location as the one created in the backdrop

(Backdrop is just another tikz pictures as mentioned in the title)

or can I nest pictures?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\backdrop
\end {tikzpicture}
```

(I haven't tried this to see if it works)

Comment: Is backdrop in pdf or png... format? If yes, then I hope it should be possible. But not as you mentioned above.

Comment: Can you describe `\backdrop` a little ? Nested tikzpictures are not recommended but it's possible if you take care but it's often possible to avoid this kind of situation !

Comment: @HarishKumar as the title says "Combine tikz pictures" (this should imply backdrop is another tikzpicture)

Comment: @Altermundus I can avoid it by keeping the tikspicture open but then I cannot modify it easily. It would even be nice to create the picture in one spot, at some other stuff then modify it later on. e.g., give the tikzpicture a name then use a sort of modify environment to reopen it.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Given that you know what `\backdrop` is and we don't, it seems that the simplest thing would be simply to try it and see what happens.  Then if something doesn't quite work, you can ask specifically about that and it might be easier for us to help.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46818/86 (about nesting TikZ environments).

Answer (score 4):

Somthing like that?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\backdrop}{
   \draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
   % more TikZ code
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \backdrop
   \draw [thick, green] (1,1) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2]
   \backdrop
   \draw [thick, red] (1,1) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

When using layer it even doesn’t matter where you call `\backdrop`:

```
\pgfdeclarelayer{backdrop}
\pgfsetlayers{backdrop,main}

\newcommand{\backdrop}{
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{backdrop}
         \fill [yellow] (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
         \draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
         % more TikZ code
      \end{pgfonlayer}
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping to have backdrop in it's own tikzpicture environment. I was going to use your idea but mine is a slightly more complex. The reason is, I might want to have \backdrop as it's own standalone picture in many cases and then combine it with other pictures. I was curious if tikz could easily "merge" picture environments properly.

Comment: @Uiy: Yes I thought that you wanted that, and I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46596/4918 and tried to add the `{tikzpicture}` inly if we’re not in one already but I had no success in my short test. You may try it yourself …

Comment: What I would actually like is to "pre-compile" the "backdrop" so it is faster. Sort of convert it to an image then use the image... (automatically of course)

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to help you because you gave not much information and no [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) , that at least shows how your backdrop will look like.

Here’s my new suggest.

Create the backdrop image using the `standalone` class:

```
% backdrop.tex
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw [blue] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Give the image file `backdrop.pdf` that we now can include in the main document. For that we create a command `\backdrop` with three *optional* arguments:

```
\backdrop(coordiate)[node options][graphic options]
```

The first on takes a TikZ coordinate like `0,0`, the second passes options to the `node` and the latter passes options to `\includegraphics`. Since all are optional you must give an empty second argument if you want to use only the third (see the example below). If you call `\backdrop` in text mode it will certainly ignore the first two arguments. Note: You can only change the node *containing* the image but not the image itself because it’s a PDF …

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

% define a default style for the backdrop node
\tikzset{
   backdrop node/.style={%
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      anchor=south west,
   },
}

% define the layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{backdrop}
\pgfsetlayers{backdrop,main}

% defin the command to print the backdrop image
\NewDocumentCommand{\backdrop}{D(){0,0} O{} O{}}{%
   \tikzifinpicture{% inside a TikZ-Picture
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{backdrop}
         \node at (#1) [backdrop node,#2]
               {\includegraphics[#3]{backdrop}};
      \end{pgfonlayer}
   }{% in normal Text
      \includegraphics[#3]{backdrop}
   }%
}

\begin{document}
\section*{outside}
\backdrop
\section*{inside}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \backdrop
   \fill [yellow] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
   \draw [red, ultra thick] (1,1) -- (4,4);
   \backdrop(6,0)
   \backdrop[rotate=30]
   \backdrop[][width=1cm]
   \backdrop(8.5,2.5)[anchor=center][width=3cm]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thats the result:
[image: result]