# Merge two TikZ pictures into one

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, combine

Is it possible to merge two existing TikZ pictures into one? 
I have two pictures of this type and want to set them beneath each other in one `tikzpicture` environment (and adding some arrows between both pictures) without editing all the coordinates :

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2.1, smooth, scale=0.8]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3.2);
  \draw[] (1,0) -- (1,-0.15) node[below] {$\alpha_0$};
  \draw[color=red,thick,samples=500] plot (\x,{3*exp(-5*(\x-1)^2});
  \draw[color=blue,dashed,thick,samples=500] plot (\x,{3*exp(-5*(\x-1)^2});
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: It's quite hard to tell without a MWE, but  maybe you are looking for the `scope` environment provided by `tikz/pgf`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 9):

You can simply include both your TikZ pictures into one by placing them inside nodes of yet another TikZ picture. As long as you don't seriously have to worry about compilation time it is OK to write something like the code below.
It also helps with the arrows in between.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node (a) at (0,0)
         {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
               \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}
         };
        \node (b) at (a.south) [anchor=north,yshift=-1cm]
         {
            \tikz\fill[blue] (0,0) circle (0.7cm);
         };
       \draw [<->] (a)--(b);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the example code]

Comment: In general, nesting `tikzpicture`s should be avoided: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46792/

Answer (score 8):

To shift part of a picture one can use a `{scope}` and one of the shifting options:

- `shift=<coordinate>` (Argument has do be in braces `{}` when it contains a comma `,`)
- `xshift=<distance>`
- `yshift=<distance>`

In the following example I’ll use `shift` and a predefined coordinate `(shift)` (the name doesn’t matter) to have easy access to the shifting later.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Shifting coordinate (optional)
  \coordinate (shift) at (0,-3);
  % First image, without a scope
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \fill (2,-1) rectangle ++(4,2);
  %% named node
  \node (A 1) at (8,0) {Node 1};
  %% named coordinate
  \coordinate (C 1) at (10,0);
  \begin{scope}[shift=(shift)]
    \draw (8,0) circle (1);
    \fill (2,-1) rectangle ++(4,2);
    \node (A 2) at (0,0) {Node 2};
    \coordinate (C 2) at (10,0);
  \end{scope}
  % Connection line
  %% A) use named coordinates nodes
  \draw [red,->] (A 1) -- (A 2);
  %% B) use named coordinates
  \draw [blue, ->] (C 2) -- (C 1);
  %% C) use calculation with (shift)
  \draw [green, ->] (0,0) -- ($(8,0)+(shift)$);
  %% D) shift a single coordinate
  \draw [orange, ->] (2,-1) -- ([shift=(shift)] 4,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting image]

To access both coordinate systems I’d prefer using named nodes or coordinates which is basically the same (red and blue arrow in the example). But it is also possible to use the `calc` library and add the shifting manually, by using `($<coord>+(shift)$)` (green arrow). As  Qrrbrbirlbel stated it is also possible to apply the `shift` option to a single coordinat (orange arrow).

Comment: The shifting options can be applied to single coordinates too (without the `calc` library): `\draw [green, ->] (0,0) -- ([shift=(shift)] 8,0);`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you I added that to my answer.