# Access loop variable outside loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Here's what I have created, but how could I access the loop variable `\n` outside the foreach loop so that I could write sth like this:

```
\n = \n + 1 % this is definitely not right, and it seems I couldn't reference \n outside foreach loop
\node[element,fill=white,xshift=\n*1cm](l_N\n){...};
```

instead of hardcoding the value.

This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
  element/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=red!20,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm},
  outer/.style={circle,draw=green,fill=green!20,thick,inner sep=10pt,minimum size=7cm}
  ]
  \node[outer,draw=green] (A) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i [count=\n] in {0, 1, ..., 3}
         \node[element,xshift=\n*1cm](l_N\n){\i};


      \node[element,fill=white,xshift=5*1cm](l_N5){...};
      \node[element,xshift=6cm](l_N9){9};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \node[outer,draw=green,right=of A] (B) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \i [count=\n] in {0, 1, ..., 3}
         \node[element,xshift=\n*1cm](r_N\n){\i};

      \node[element,fill=white,xshift=5*1cm](r_N5){...};
      \node[element,xshift=6cm](r_N9){9};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\draw[thick,dashed] (l_N9) -- (r_N1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: A related good read : [problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way would be to save the value in a global:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\LastLoopValue}{No value}
\begin{document}

\foreach \i  [count=\n] in {0, 2, ..., 14} {
    \i,
    \xdef\LastLoopValue{\n}%
}

Outside of loop, count=\LastLoopValue
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to increment `\LastLoopValue`? For example:`Another line count=\LastLoopValue+1`

Comment: @AlbertNetymk: There are numerous ways to increment values -- there should be a question here that answers that.  But, if you don't find it, you should post a new question as incrementing a value is _not_ related to accessing a loop variable outside of the loop.  But, _one_ way would be to define `\newcommand{\Increment}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1+1}\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}}`, and then using `\Increment{\LastLoopValue}` will provide what you desire (assuming you desire an integer value).

Answer (score 1):

The `\foreach` loop is fantastic tool, but has the particularity to create and run inside a group. So every action (`\def`, `\clip`, ...) that is limited by the scope will not survive outside the loop.

In some situation it is good to know that there are other loops that don't run in a group. For example the [xint bundle](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/xint) has such loops. Here is one example :

```
\documentclass[preview, border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand*{\LastLoopValue}{No value}
\newcounter{loopCounter}

\begin{document}

  \xintFor* #1 in {\xintSeq[2]{0}{14}} \do{
    #1, \def\LastLoopValue{#1}
    \stepcounter{loopCounter}
  }

  ... outside of loop, LastLoopValue=\LastLoopValue, loopCounter=\arabic{loopCounter}

\end{document}
```

[image]