# How to access length of inner list in pgffor

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, pgffor

I have a list of lists, and I'm using nested `\foreach` loops to iterate through them.  By using `[count=\var]`, I'm able to use `\var` to access the length of the outer loop (after I've iterated through).  However, I am not able to use this method to access the length of the inner loops.  In my case, all the inner loops should have the same length, but technically I wanted to access the length of the last of the inner loops.  Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% The first two work:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \from [count=\to] in {2,3,1} {
    \draw (\from,1) -- (\to,2);
  }
  \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \from [count=\to] in {1,3,2} {
    \draw (\from,1) -- (\to,2);
  }
  \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

% This one does not work:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \list [count=\row] in {{2,3,1},{1,3,2}} {
    \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
      \draw (\from,\row) -- (\to,\row+1);
    }
  }
  \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,\row+1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's what I want to end up with:

[image: desired result]

Comment: This solution would help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115428/124842 (as workaround). So 1. in preamble: `\newcommand*{\LastLoopValue}{0} `, 2. in second for loop \xdef\LastLoopValue{\to} and finaly 3. `\draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (0.5+\LastLoopValue,\row+1.5);` instead of `\draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,\row+1.5);`

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works as a workaround.  Unfortunately, I really dislike using global variables (which LaTeX really wants me to use), so I'm going to keep looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses LaTeX counters in combination with TikZ macros.  All counter operations are global.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{to}
\newcounter{row}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setcounter{to}{0}
  \foreach \from in {2,3,1} {
    \stepcounter{to}
    \draw (\from,1) -- ({\theto},2);
  }
  \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\theto+0.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setcounter{to}{0}
  \foreach \from in {1,3,2} {
    \stepcounter{to}
    \draw (\from,1) -- (\theto,2);
  }
  \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\theto+0.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \setcounter{row}{0}
  \foreach \list in {{2,3,1},{1,3,2}} {
    \stepcounter{row}
    \setcounter{to}{0}
    \foreach \from in \list {
      \stepcounter{to}
      \draw (\from,\therow) -- (\theto,\therow+1);
    }
  }
  \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\theto+0.5,\therow+1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks!  This works for this case, but I'm averse to using global variables (even though LaTeX really likes them).  I found another solution that has a downside of needing to iterate through the outer loop twice (and the final inner loop once).

Comment: Only global variables can get out of a \foreach step.  Presumably [count=\var] translates as `\let\var=\pgf@count`, or some sort of global variable used by tikz for all loops (hence the problem with nested loops).

Answer (score 0):

This solution has the disadvantage of needing to iterate through the list multiple times, but it avoids setting a global variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \list [count=\row] in {{2,3,1},{1,3,2}} {
    \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
      \draw (\from,\row) -- (\to,\row+1);
    }
  }
  \foreach \list [count=\count] in {{2,3,1},{1,3,2}} {
    \ifx \count \row
      \foreach \from [count=\to] in \list {
      }
      \draw[gray] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (\to+0.5,\row+1.5);
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The issue with my first version is that `\to` was out-of-scope when I was trying to use it.  This uses it when it's still in scope.