# Chains in nested tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting, tikz-chains

I am trying to draw a complex item (consisting of multiple `\node`s) as a cohesive whole using a nested `\tikz`picture.
My outermost picture uses a chain, onto which every `\node` is put.

My inner picture uses a chain as well, but that's supposed to be a different one than the outer chain.

This structure causes an error:

> Package pgf Error: No shape named chain-2 is known.

How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=5mm,
    every node/.style={on chain},
    connect/.append style={join=by ->},
    point/.style={coordinate},
    l/.style={draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc=0},
    c/.style={draw},
    r/.style={draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle left arc=0},
    cozy/.style={node distance=0}]
\node [point] {};
\node [connect] (lcr) {\tikz{[start chain, cozy]
    \node [l] (l) {L};
    \node [c] (c) {C};
    \node [r] (r) {R};
}};
\node [point, connect] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I have utilized [@Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161527/31877) (which uses boxes to store the inner tikzpicture) to get rid of the error. Even though it gets me closer to a solution, my actual situation won't be fixed by it, because now latex seems to think `\node`s are at a different location than where the're eventually drawn:

[image: bad positions]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,shapes.misc}

\newsavebox\mybox
\tikzset{
    l/.style={draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle right arc=0},
    c/.style={draw},
    r/.style={draw, rounded rectangle, rounded rectangle left arc=0},
    cozy/.style={node distance=0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\savebox\mybox{%
\tikz[start chain,every node/.style={on chain},node distance=-\pgflinewidth]
{
    \node [l] (l) {L};
    \node [c] (c) {C};
    \node [r] (r) {R};
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=5mm,
    every node/.style={on chain},
    connect/.append style={join=by ->},
    point/.style={coordinate},
    group/.style={inner sep=0, outer sep=0}]
\node [point] {};
\node [connect, group] (lcr) {\usebox\mybox};
\node [point, connect] {};
{[]
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (l.south east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe I just need to get rid of the `chain` in my nested picture... or for that matter, the lose the entire nested picture, and stick to a single level of tikz.

Comment: I think nesting `tikzpictures` is not a good idea. What is it that you are trying to achieve?  See for instance [Problem with overlay when a tikzpicture is inside another tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture).

Comment: I want to draw a chain where one of the nodes on the chain is a complex shape of my own design. This shape happens to be constructed using a chain as well. Later on, I want to draw arrows pointing towards components of the inner tikzpicture, across the *entire* image.

Comment: Sounds like you need `\tikzmark`, but not sure without seeing a picture of what is desired. See the link in the first comment as to why it isn't a good idea.

Comment: Just a thought: any possibility of using the new "pic" functionality for this?

Comment: Start by giving the chains proper names, i.e. `start chain=outer chain` and `start chain=inner chain` (→ `on chain=outer chain`, `on chain=inner chain`), otherwise TikZ might not differentiate between them. If you're just `going right` (the default direction of a chain) you could just use a `\matrix` (e.g. the [`\tikzCenterNodes` macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662773) can help here). A matrix is almost a node in itself. Maybe you actually need a `branch` or something totally different.

Comment: Without much information about the end product I'd vote to close this question.