# How to exclude certain elements from a built path loop in a neural network drawing with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I learned a nice way to make a neural network (nn) from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618305/260996)

When I edit it for my personal nn as follows:

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifnumcomp
\usepackage{listofitems} % for \readlist to create arrays    
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myorange}{orange!70!red!60!black}
\colorlet{mydarkred}{red!30!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{blue!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkgreen}{green!30!black}
\definecolor{iceberg}{rgb}{0.44, 0.65, 0.82}
\definecolor{firebrick}{rgb}{0.7, 0.13, 0.13}
\definecolor{outerspace}{rgb}{0.25, 0.29, 0.3}
\definecolor{lemonchiffon}{rgb}{1.0, 0.98, 0.8}
\definecolor{flavescent}{rgb}{0.97, 0.91, 0.56}
\definecolor{floralwhite}{rgb}{1.0, 0.98, 0.94}
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{electriclime}{rgb}{0.8, 1.0, 0.0}
\tikzstyle{node}=[thick,circle,draw=myblue,minimum size=22,inner sep=0.5,outer sep=0.6]
\tikzstyle{node in}=[node,myblue!30!black,draw=myblue!30!black,fill=floralwhite]
\tikzstyle{node hidden}=[node,blue!20!black,draw=myblue!5!black,fill=airforceblue!15]
\tikzstyle{node convol}=[node,orange!20!black,draw=myorange!30!black,fill=myorange!20]
\tikzstyle{node out}=[node,red!20!black,draw=myred!30!black,fill=firebrick!20]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[thick,mydarkblue] %,line cap=round
\tikzstyle{connect arrow}=[-{Latex[length=4,width=3.5]},thick,mydarkblue,shorten <=0.5,shorten >=1]
\tikzset{ % node styles, numbered for easy mapping with \nstyle
        node 1/.style={node in},
        node 2/.style={node hidden},
        node 3/.style={node out},
        }
\def\nstyle{int(\lay<\Nnodlen?min(2,\lay):3)} % map layer number onto 1, 2, or 3

\begin{document}
% NEURAL NETWORK
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.2cm,y=1.4cm]
\message{^^JNeural network, shifted}
\readlist\Nnod{3,5,5,5,5,5,1} % array of number of nodes per layer
\readlist\Nstr{n,m,m,m,k} % array of string number of nodes per layer
\readlist\Cstr{\strut x,a^{(\prev)},a^{(\prev)},a^{(\prev)},y} % array of coefficient symbol per layer
\def\yshift{0.5} % shift last node for dots
\message{^^J  Layer}
\foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{ % loop over layers
    \def\lay{\Ncnt} % alias of index of current layer
    \pgfmathsetmacro\prev{int(\Ncnt-1)} % number of previous layer
    \message{\lay,}
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\c=int(\i==\N); \y=\N/2-\i-\c*\yshift;
    \index=(\i<\N?int(\i):"\Nstr[\lay]");
    \x=\lay; \n=\nstyle;}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
    % NODES
    \node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y){}; %{$\Cstr[\lay]_{\index}$};
    % CONNECTIONS
    \ifnum\lay>1 % connect to previous layer
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\Nnod[\prev]}{ % loop over nodes in previous layer
    \draw[connect,white,line width=1.2] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
    \draw[connect] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
    %\draw[connect] (N\prev-\j.0) -- (N\lay-\i.180); % connect to left
    }
    \fi % else: nothing to connect first layer
    }
     \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.5] {$\vdots$};
    }
    % LABELS
    \node[above=0.8,align=center,myblue!50!black] at (N1-1.90) {Input\\[-0.2em]Layers};
    \node[above=0,align=center,airforceblue] at (N4-1.90) {Hidden Layers};
    \node[above=60,align=center,myred!60!black] at (N\Nnodlen-1.90) {Output\\[-0.2em]Layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there are three vertical dots (`$\vdots$`) which express the nodes iteration among the "Input Layers," "Hidden Layers," and "Output Layer." When I tried to only delete (or cancel) the `$\vdots$` for the "output layer," all `$\vdots$` disappeared. So I have to keep the `$\vdots$` as follows:

[image]

**My question is:** How can I only keep the `$\vdots$` for my input layer and hidden layer, but not for the output layer? Or how to set any single layer should exclude the iteration sign `$\vdots$` accordingly?

Thank you in advance, I hope the attached pic helps me illustrate my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing the [`\tikzCenterNodes` macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662670/16595) into `\tikzMatrixNodes` this diagram can recreated without … whatever is happening in your code.

In addition the `graphs` library helps to draw all the lines.

There's a way with the `parse` key to loop over all hidden layers but I couldn't figure out a clean way. Here I'll just add the nodes manually but use the `\foreach` loop to skip the `\vdots` node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.positioning-plus,graphs}
\tikzset{
  node matrix/.style={row sep=y_node_dist, column sep=x_node_dist,
    every outer matrix/.append style={/pgf/inner sep=+0pt, /pgf/outer sep=+0pt, draw=none, fill=none, shape=rectangle}},
  node matrix/node/.style={node contents=,anchor=center,
    name/.expanded={\tikzmatrixname_\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=1 \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\else\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\fi},
    {nm \ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=1 \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\else\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\fi}/.try},
  node matrix/place 1st node/.code args={#1,#2}{\node[node matrix/node,#1];},
  node matrix/place other nodes/.style args={#1,#2}{/tikz/node matrix/place oth node/.list={#2}},
  vertical   node matrix/.style={/tikz/node matrix/place oth node/.code={\pgfmatrixendrow  \node[node matrix/node,##1];}},
  horizontal node matrix/.style={/tikz/node matrix/place oth node/.code={\pgfmatrixnextcell\node[node matrix/node,##1];}}}
\newcommand*\tikzMatrixNodes[2][1]{%
  \matrix[every node matrix/.try,node matrix,#1]{
    \tikzset{node matrix/place 1st node={#2},node matrix/place other nodes={#2}}\\};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=5mm and 10mm,
  layers/.style={circle, thick, draw, minimum size=+5mm},
  input/.style ={layers, fill=yellow!30},
  hidden/.style={layers, fill=blue!30},
  output/.style={layers, fill=red!30},
  every node matrix/.style={vertical node matrix},
  second to last/.style={
    nm #1/.style={node contents=\vdots, text height=2ex, fill=none, draw=none, minimum size=+0pt,inner sep=+0pt, shape=rectangle},
    row #1/.append style={row sep=.5*y_node_dist}, row \inteval{#1-1}/.append style={row sep=.5*y_node_dist}},
]

\tikzMatrixNodes[name=hidden0, nodes=input, second to last=3]{,,,}
\foreach \hidden[count=\lastHidden from 0] in {1,...,5}{% chains?
  \tikzMatrixNodes[
    right=of hidden\lastHidden, name=hidden\hidden,
    nodes=hidden, second to last=5]{,,,,,}}
\node[right=of hidden5, output](output){};

\path[thick, blue] graph[use existing nodes]{
  {\foreach \x in {1,2,4}{hidden0_\x}}
    -- [complete bipartite] {\foreach \x in {1,...,4,6}{hidden1_\x}}
    -- [complete bipartite] {\foreach \x in {1,...,4,6}{hidden2_\x}}
    -- [complete bipartite] {\foreach \x in {1,...,4,6}{hidden3_\x}}
    -- [complete bipartite] {\foreach \x in {1,...,4,6}{hidden4_\x}}
    -- [complete bipartite] {\foreach \x in {1,...,4,6}{hidden5_\x}}
    -- {output};
};

\path[nodes={align=center}]
  (hidden3_1.north)     node[above,blue!70] (hl) {Hidden Layers} % could've been a label
  (hidden0_1|-hl.south) node[above,blue]         {Input\\Layers}
  (output|-hl.south)    node[above,red]          {Output\\Layers};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is much easier to understand and read than my original version.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried to understand the code - it is not minimal at all. I just notice that it uses `\ifnum\lay ... \fi` - so you can do the same like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifnumcomp
\usepackage{listofitems} % for \readlist to create arrays    
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myorange}{orange!70!red!60!black}
\colorlet{mydarkred}{red!30!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{blue!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkgreen}{green!30!black}
\definecolor{iceberg}{rgb}{0.44, 0.65, 0.82}
\definecolor{firebrick}{rgb}{0.7, 0.13, 0.13}
\definecolor{outerspace}{rgb}{0.25, 0.29, 0.3}
\definecolor{lemonchiffon}{rgb}{1.0, 0.98, 0.8}
\definecolor{flavescent}{rgb}{0.97, 0.91, 0.56}
\definecolor{floralwhite}{rgb}{1.0, 0.98, 0.94}
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}
\definecolor{electriclime}{rgb}{0.8, 1.0, 0.0}
\tikzstyle{node}=[thick,circle,draw=myblue,minimum size=22,inner sep=0.5,outer sep=0.6]
\tikzstyle{node in}=[node,myblue!30!black,draw=myblue!30!black,fill=floralwhite]
\tikzstyle{node hidden}=[node,blue!20!black,draw=myblue!5!black,fill=airforceblue!15]
\tikzstyle{node convol}=[node,orange!20!black,draw=myorange!30!black,fill=myorange!20]
\tikzstyle{node out}=[node,red!20!black,draw=myred!30!black,fill=firebrick!20]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[thick,mydarkblue] %,line cap=round
\tikzstyle{connect arrow}=[-{Latex[length=4,width=3.5]},thick,mydarkblue,shorten <=0.5,shorten >=1]
\tikzset{ % node styles, numbered for easy mapping with \nstyle
        node 1/.style={node in},
        node 2/.style={node hidden},
        node 3/.style={node out},
        }
\def\nstyle{int(\lay<\Nnodlen?min(2,\lay):3)} % map layer number onto 1, 2, or 3

\begin{document}
% NEURAL NETWORK
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.2cm,y=1.4cm]
\message{^^JNeural network, shifted}
\readlist\Nnod{3,5,5,5,5,5,1} % array of number of nodes per layer
\readlist\Nstr{n,m,m,m,k} % array of string number of nodes per layer
\readlist\Cstr{\strut x,a^{(\prev)},a^{(\prev)},a^{(\prev)},y} % array of coefficient symbol per layer
\def\yshift{0.5} % shift last node for dots
\message{^^J  Layer}
\foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{ % loop over layers
    \def\lay{\Ncnt} % alias of index of current layer
    \pgfmathsetmacro\prev{int(\Ncnt-1)} % number of previous layer
    \message{\lay,}
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\c=int(\i==\N); \y=\N/2-\i-\c*\yshift;
    \index=(\i<\N?int(\i):"\Nstr[\lay]");
    \x=\lay; \n=\nstyle;}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
    % NODES
    \node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y){}; %{$\Cstr[\lay]_{\index}$};
    % CONNECTIONS
    \ifnum\lay>1 % connect to previous layer
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\Nnod[\prev]}{ % loop over nodes in previous layer
    \draw[connect,white,line width=1.2] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
    \draw[connect] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
    %\draw[connect] (N\prev-\j.0) -- (N\lay-\i.180); % connect to left
    }
    \fi % else: nothing to connect first layer
    }
      \ifnum\lay<7 \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.5] {$\vdots$}; \fi
    }
    % LABELS
    \node[above=0.8,align=center,myblue!50!black] at (N1-1.90) {Input\\[-0.2em]Layers};
    \node[above=0,align=center,airforceblue] at (N4-1.90) {Hidden Layers};
    \node[above=60,align=center,myred!60!black] at (N\Nnodlen-1.90) {Output\\[-0.2em]Layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Neural network]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for too many unrelated color settings. If I understand right, the solution (\ifnum\lay ... \fi) can exclude the dots in the Input layers and Output layers, but it is hard to change those in the Hidden layers, am I right?

Comment: No problem - just add multiple lines like `\ifnum\lay=4 \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.5] {$\vdots$}; \fi`