# How can I connect TikZ nodes with multiple-corner lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am currently working on a flow chart. The mwe (see below) produces the following output:
[image: flow chart as PDFLaTeX outputs it]

How can I achieve the following, desired output, ideally without having to declare additional coordinates/nodes? I want the Casting nodes to be connected to the horizontal line between Basic Oxygen Converter and Electric Arc Furnace through a vertical line. Also, how can I center the whole group of Casting nodes relative to the nodes Basic Oxygen Converter and Electric Arc Furnace?
[image: flow chart as I want it to be]

### mwe

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
every node/.style={rectangle,draw,inner ysep=3mm,text centered}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=20mm and 10mm]

\node (boc) {Basic Oxygen Converter};
\node[right=of boc] (eaf) {Electric Arc Furnace};

\draw (boc) -- (eaf);

\node[below left=15mm and 10mm of $(boc) !.5! (eaf)$] (mediumslabcasting) {Medium Slab Casting};
\node[left=of mediumslabcasting] (thickslabcasting) {Thick Slab Casting};
\node[right=of mediumslabcasting] (bloomcasting) {Bloom Casting};
\node[right=of bloomcasting] (billetcasting) {Billet Casting};

\draw (mediumslabcasting) |- ($(boc) !.5! (eaf)$);
\draw (thickslabcasting) |- ($(boc) !.5! (eaf)$);
\draw (bloomcasting) |- ($(boc) !.5! (eaf)$);
\draw (billetcasting) |- ($(boc) !.5! (eaf)$);
                        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried having a look at https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/ I think it has some good templates for what you are after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include your nodes into two different `matrix` nodes which can be easlily positioned one above the other. After that you just need to draw the links. I've used two auxiliary coordinates.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
    mynode/.style= {anchor=center, rectangle, draw, inner ysep=3mm, text centered}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=20mm and 10mm]

\matrix (top) [matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, column sep=10mm]{
Basic Oxygen Converter & 
Electric Arc Furnace\\};

\matrix (bottom) [matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, below=1cm of top, column sep=5mm] {
Medium Slab Casting & Thick Slab Casting & Bloom Casting & Billet Casting\\
};

\draw (top-1-1.east) -- coordinate (aux1) (top-1-2.west);
\path (aux1) -- coordinate (aux2) (aux1|-bottom-1-1.north);
\draw (aux1)--(aux2);

\foreach \i [count=\ni] in  {1,2,3,4}
\draw (bottom-1-\ni.north)|-(aux2);                        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly how I wanted it to be!

Answer (score 4):

[Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662665) already explained how to use a `\matrix`, I'd recommend a more automatic way to place a bunch of nodes side-by-side by using the macro

```
\tikzCenterNodes[<options>]{list of <opt>/<text>}
```

which constructs a 1-row matrix with the `<options>` (this should be used for naming the matrix and placing it) and the nodes of the list, where `<opt>` is used between `\node` and the text `<text>` of the node.

I didn't add any safe-guarding in case only one node is used with `\tikzCenterNodes` but in that case you can use the normal `\node` macro.

Since you used the `every node` style (which also applies to the `\matrix`) I'm using the `every outer matrix` style to remove or reset a few default values for the matrix since we want it to be tightly fit around our row of nodes.

---

I'm using [my libraries](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext)

- `ext.positioning-plus`

  for the PGFMath functions `x_node_dist` and `y_node_dist`
  so that we don't have to give the node distance
  in one than more places
  (the horizontal node distance becomes the `column sep` value) and
- `ext.paths.ortho`

  which allows us to use [orthogonal connections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45347/16595) of the form `|-|`
  (`vertical horizontal vertical`) where I again use `y_node_dist`
  so that the horizontal part of the `|-|` connection
  is halfway between the nodes.

This has one auxiliary coordinate `mid` that is halfway between the borders of the top two nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.positioning-plus,ext.paths.ortho}
\newcommand*\tikzCenterNodes[2][1]{% only
  \matrix[
    every outer matrix/.append style={/pgf/inner sep=+0pt, /pgf/outer sep=+0pt, draw=none, fill=none},
    /utils/place 1st node/.code args={##1/##2,##3}{\node##1{##2};},
    /utils/place oth node/.code args={##1/##2}{\pgfmatrixnextcell\node##1{##2};},
    /utils/place other nodes/.style args={##1,##2}{/utils/place oth node/.list={##2}},
    column sep=x_node_dist,
    #1] {
    \tikzset{/utils/place 1st node={#2},/utils/place other nodes={#2}}
    \\};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=20mm and 10mm,
  nodes={rectangle, draw, inner ysep=3mm, text depth=+0pt}
]
\tikzCenterNodes[name=toprow]{
  (boc)/Basic Oxygen Converter,
  (eaf)/Electric Arc Furnace}
\tikzCenterNodes[name=bottomrow, below=of toprow]{
  (msc)/Medium Slab Casting,
  (tsc)/Thick Slab Casting,
  (bmc)/Bloom Casting,
  (btc)/Billet Casting}

\path (eaf) edge coordinate (mid) (boc)
  [ % half of node distance so
    % that the horizontal part is halfway between nodes
    vertical horizontal vertical, % to path = {|-|(\tikztotarget)}
    ortho={distance=-.5*y_node_dist}
  ] (mid) edge (msc)
          edge (tsc)
          edge (bmc)
          edge (btc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]