# How can I add "dots" between the nodes of this Latex neural network in the input and hidden layer? I want 5 nodes in the input layer not 12

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, neuralnetwork

````
% latexdraw.com
% 21/02/2021 at 22:20

\documentclass[border = 0.2cm]{standalone}

% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin {document}

% Input layer neurons'number
\newcommand{\inputnum}{12} 
% Hidden layer neurons'number
\newcommand{\hiddennum}{12}  
% Output layer neurons'number
\newcommand{\outputnum}{1} 

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Input Layer
\foreach \i in {1,...,\inputnum}
{
    \node[circle, 
        minimum size = 6mm,
        fill=orange!30] (Input-\i) at (0,-\i) {};
}

% Hidden Layer
\foreach \i in {1,...,\hiddennum}
{
    \node[circle, 
        minimum size = 6mm,
        fill=teal!50,
        yshift=(\hiddennum-\inputnum)*5 mm
    ] (Hidden-\i) at (2.5,-\i) {};
}

% Output Layer
\foreach \i in {1,...,\outputnum}
{
    \node[circle, 
        minimum size = 6mm,
        fill=purple!50,
        yshift=(\outputnum-\inputnum)*5 mm
    ] (Output-\i) at (5,-\i) {};
}

% Connect neurons In-Hidden
\foreach \i in {1,...,\inputnum}
{
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\hiddennum}
    {
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt] (Input-\i) -- (Hidden-\j); 
    }
}

% Connect neurons Hidden-Out
\foreach \i in {1,...,\hiddennum}
{
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\outputnum}
    {
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt] (Hidden-\i) -- (Output-\j);
    }
}

% Inputs
\foreach \i in {1,...,\inputnum}
{            
    \draw[<-, shorten >=1pt] (Input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
        node[left]{$x_{\i}$};
}

% Outputs
\foreach \i in {1,...,\outputnum}
{            
    \draw[->, shorten >=1pt] (Output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
        node[right]{$y_{\i}$};
}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Can I interest you in [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662773)? Where should the dots be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting [my answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662773/16595) by

- adjusting the styles `layers`, `input`, `hidden` and `output`,
- defining the `every pin edge` style,
- removing all the hidden layers except for one and
- adding the actual “pins”.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.positioning-plus,graphs}
\tikzset{
  node matrix/.style={row sep=y_node_dist, column sep=x_node_dist,
    every outer matrix/.append style={/pgf/inner sep=+0pt, /pgf/outer sep=+0pt, draw=none, fill=none, shape=rectangle}},
  node matrix/node/.style={node contents=,anchor=center,
    name/.expanded={\tikzmatrixname_\ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=1 \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\else\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\fi},
    {nm \ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=1 \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn\else\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\fi}/.try},
  node matrix/place 1st node/.code args={#1,#2}{\node[node matrix/node,#1];},
  node matrix/place other nodes/.style args={#1,#2}{/tikz/node matrix/place oth node/.list={#2}},
  vertical   node matrix/.style={/tikz/node matrix/place oth node/.code={\pgfmatrixendrow  \node[node matrix/node,##1];}},
  horizontal node matrix/.style={/tikz/node matrix/place oth node/.code={\pgfmatrixnextcell\node[node matrix/node,##1];}}}
\newcommand*\tikzMatrixNodes[2][1]{%
  \matrix[every node matrix/.try,node matrix,#1]{
    \tikzset{node matrix/place 1st node={#2},node matrix/place other nodes={#2}}\\};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=5mm and 10mm,
  layers/.style={circle, minimum size=+6mm},
  input/.style ={layers, fill=orange!30},
  hidden/.style={layers, fill=teal!50},
  output/.style={layers, fill=purple!50},
  every node matrix/.style={vertical node matrix},
  second to last/.style={
    nm #1/.style={node contents=\vdots, text height=2ex, path only, minimum size=+0pt,inner sep=+0pt, shape=rectangle},
    row #1/.append style={row sep=.5*y_node_dist}, row \pgfinteval{#1-1}/.append style={row sep=.5*y_node_dist}},
  every pin edge/.append style={<-, black, thin}
]

\tikzMatrixNodes[name=hidden0, nodes=input, second to last=5]{,,,,,}
\foreach \hidden/\number in {1, 2, 3, 4, 6/n}
  \path (hidden0_\hidden) [late options={pin={left:$x_\number$}}];
\foreach \hidden[count=\lastHidden from 0] in {1}{% loop can be removed using
  \tikzMatrixNodes[                               % right=of hidden0, name=hidden=1
    right=of hidden\lastHidden, name=hidden\hidden,
    nodes=hidden, second to last=5]{,,,,,}}
\node[right=of hidden1, output, pin={[pin edge=->]right:$y_1$}](output){};

\path[shorten >=1pt] graph[use existing nodes]{
  {\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,6}{hidden0_\x}}
    -> [complete bipartite] {\foreach \x in {1,...,4,6}{hidden1_\x}}
    -> {output};
};

%\path[nodes={align=center}]
%  (hidden1_1.north)     node[above,blue!70] (hl) {Hidden\\Layers} % could've been a label
%  (hidden0_1|-hl.south) node[above,blue]         {Input\\Layers}
%  (output|-hl.south)    node[above,red]          {Output\\Layers};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]