# Using multiple styles inside a TikZ node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to do something like:

[image]

using PGF styles in TikZ

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=mwe.png}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/style A/.style = {text=blue},
  /tikz/style B/.style = {text=red},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [thin, draw, style A] at (1,3) {Style A};
  \node [thin, draw, style B] at (1,2) {Style B};
  \node [thin, draw] at (1,1) {Style A + Style B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the "Style A + Style B" is always the same color. How can I do to get "Style A" in `style A` and "Style B" in `style b` and the "+" in the node style?

Of course I could use something like `{\color{blue}Style A} + {\color{red}Style B}` but it's not very flexible. I prefer to use styles instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, do you want it so that only "Style A" uses style A? As in, a defined set of words is written like that? Or any text? Because the solutions might change.

Comment: If it is possible for any text I prefer that solution.

Comment: Then automatic becomes more difficult. How would you distinguish what text is colored with which color? There needs to be a rule for Latex to use, it cannot read your mind. :D

Comment: I was wondering how I can write something like: `\node [thin, draw] at (1,1) {\tikzusestyle[style a]{Style A} + \tikzusestyle[style a]{Style B}};` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @peter-grill's answer (thanks to him) I came up with that working solution that work for my needs:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=mwe.png}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{%
  /tikz/Inner Style/.style={ultra thin, draw},
  /tikz/style A/.style = {text=blue},
  /tikz/style B/.style = {text=red},
  /tikz/nested/.style = {%
    baseline=(current bounding box.base),
    every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base, Inner Style},
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [thin, draw, nested] at (1,-1) {%
    {\tikz \node[style A]{e};}%
    {\tikz \node[]{epe};}%
    {\tikz \node[style B]{e};}
  };
  \node [thin, draw, nested] at (1,0) {%
    {\tikz \node[style A]{Style a};}%
    {\tikz \node[]{+};}%
    {\tikz \node[style B]{Style b};}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The trick is to play with the `baseline` and `anchor` options.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to work for *any* text then I can see two options which allow you to keep the flexability in that you only need to change the color once.

The first method uses `\colorlet` to define the colors to use and then applies the solution you proposed via `\textcolor`.

```
\colorlet{StyleAColor}{blue}
\colorlet{StyleBColor}{red}

\tikzset{
    style A/.style={text=StyleAColor},
    style B/.style={text=StyleBColor},
}

\node [thin, draw] at (1,1) {\textcolor{StyleAColor}{Style A} + \textcolor{StyleBColor}{Style B}};
```

The second option involves nesting `tikzpictures` and this is *not* recommended:

```
\node [thin, draw] at (1,0) {
    {\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[style A, Inner Style] {Style A};} 
    {\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[Inner Style] {+};}
    {\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[style B, Inner Style] {Style B};}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{StyleAColor}{blue}
\colorlet{StyleBColor}{red}

\tikzset{
    Inner Style/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
    style A/.style={text=StyleAColor},
    style B/.style={text=StyleBColor},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [thin, draw, style A] at (1,3) {Style A};
  \node [thin, draw, style B] at (1,2) {Style B};
  \node [thin, draw] at (1,1) {\textcolor{StyleAColor}{Style A} + \textcolor{StyleBColor}{Style B}};
  \node [thin, draw] at (1,0) {
      {\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[style A, Inner Style] {Style A};} 
      {\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[Inner Style] {+};}
      {\tikz[baseline=0pt] \node[style B, Inner Style] {Style B};}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The nesting `tikzpictures` suits me. Why is not recommended to use them?

Comment: @renard: Have a look at [Problem with overlay when a tikzpicture is inside another tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture). If that is not satisfactory, you should post a general question.