# TikZ inside TikZ-node with given text width does wrong positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-node

This code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width = 3cm]{
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a\\
        \tikz{\draw (0,0) node {A} -- (1,0) node {B};}\hspace*{10cm}\\
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives this result:

[image: Result]

It places the line between A and B on the right of B and not between A and B.
Somehow specifying text width in the outer node confuses TikZ when it places the inner line.
How can I make it act normally such that the line is between A and B where it should be?

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture`s won't always work, so in general it would be better to avoid it if possible. And an unrelated comment: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently the inner tikz inherits the `text width` setting. It is visible if you draw the nodes:

[image]

The line goes from the center of node A to the center of node B, but the nodes are so wide that the text of node B ends up being left of the line.

If you reset the `text width` option, you recover the expected behavior.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width = 3cm]{
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a\\
    \tikz[text width={}]{\draw (0,0) node {A} 
      -- (1,0) node {B};}
    \hspace*{10cm}
    \\
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As Torbjørn says in the comment, [nesting tikzpictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46792/86) doesn't work well.  Here's an alternative using the `\subnode` command from the [`tikzmark`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) package (which was designed precisely for this sort of thing).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387792/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width = 3cm]{
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a\\
        \tikz{\draw (0,0) node {A} -- (1,0) node {B};}\hspace*{10cm}\\
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[text width = 3cm]{
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a\\
        \mbox{\subnode{a}{A}\hspace{1cm}\subnode{b}{B}} \\
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
    };
    \draw (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The `\mbox` is needed because otherwise the line gets broken after the `A`; I'm not sure why that is so.)

[image: Subnode to prevent nesting]