# Why is my pie chart displacing labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I have a **tikzpicture** with several nodes. Inside each node I am drawing a tikzpicture with something. Some nodes have charts, others have flowcharts etc.

Everything seems fine. The problem is when I put the two nodes below which have pie charts inside them. Why are the second pie chart's slice labels displaced? How can I fix that?

If I change the order of the charts, the second always displaces its labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Example of charts 1, 3, 5, and 7 - Total cost per case, activity, resource and time}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=.3cm and .3cm, framed]
        \node  (c1) [label=below:Total cost per activity] {\scalebox{.9}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \pie[sum = auto, radius=2.2, color={gray!10,gray!20,gray!30,gray!40,gray!50,gray!60,gray!70,gray!80}
                ]{300/a,2997/b,2400/c,900/d,1800/e,2100/f,600/g,600/h}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }};
        \node  (c2) [label=below:Total cost per resource, right=of c1] {\scalebox{.9}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \pie[radius=1.8, sum = auto, color={gray!10,gray!20,gray!30,gray!40,gray!50} 
                ]{1050/Pete,1399/Sue,2100/Mike,3900/Sara,1250/Ellen}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nesting tikzpictures can cause unexpected results (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture for example). However, if this is your actual picture, then you can also make it without nesting, for example using a tabular with two separate tikzpictures for the pie charts in the first row, and the two labels in the second row, and an `\fbox` around the tabular for the frame, among other options.

Comment: Don't nest tikzpictures inside nodes. Use `/.pic` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The `data` are given by the second variable, which is denoted by `\WCvarB`.

The colors of the slices are determined by the key `slices style`. The macro `\WCcount` gives the current number of the slice.

The `wheel data` are given by the first variable, which is denoted by `\WCvarA`. Their position is determined by the key `wheel data pos`.

The second `\wheelchart` is positioned with the key `at`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCvarB,
  radius={0}{2.5},
  slices style={
    gray!\fpeval{\WCcount*10},
    draw=black
  },
  start angle=0,
  wheel data=\WCvarA,
  wheel data pos=0.8
}
\wheelchart[
  caption=Total cost per activity
]{300/a,2997/b,2400/c,900/d,1800/e,2100/f,600/g,600/h}
\wheelchart[
  at={(6,0)},
  caption=Total cost per resource
]{1050/Pete,1399/Sue,2100/Mike,3900/Sara,1250/Ellen}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```