# Incorrect TikZ output when used with tikzmark

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

Consider the following MWE. The code of `\mypic` positions a line between two nodes. When I try to use `\mypic` with the `tikzmark` library, the positioning of the line is incorrect. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,calc}
\NewDocumentCommand{\markpic}{m}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=of pic cs:#1]{\mypic};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypic}{}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle=3pt,fill] at (0,0) {};
\draw[] (-.5,-.5) -- (.5,-.5);
\node[circle=3pt,fill] at (0,-1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

The diagram \tikzmark{C} above is incorrect.
\markpic{C}
\bigskip

The diagram below is correct.
\bigskip


\mypic

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should not nest `tikzpicture`s. By putting a `tikzpicture` in a node of another `tikzpicture` you are doing just that. If you store the inner `tikzpicture` in a box, you are safe. Alternatively you could use a `pic`, but the box is faster.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,calc}
\NewDocumentCommand{\markpic}{m}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=of pic cs:#1]{\mypic};}}
\newsavebox\mypicbox
\sbox\mypicbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle=3pt,fill] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[] (-.5,-.5) -- (.5,-.5);
    \node[circle=3pt,fill] at (0,-1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypic}{}{\usebox\mypicbox}
\begin{document}

The diagram \tikzmark{C} above is incorrect.
\markpic{C}
\bigskip

The diagram below is correct.
\bigskip


\mypic

\end{document}
```

If you really need to nest `tikzpicture`s, you need to make precautions that the inner `tikzpicture` does not use certain keys of the ambient one. In this case, the problem is `above`, which sets the anchor to `south`. Therefore the circles appear to be displaced. Alternatively, you could avoid using nodes for the circles, and just fill some circles. (In nodes, the `circle` key is a shortcut for `shape=circle`, and it does not take arguments, so `circle=3pt` is the same as `circle` in this context. You can set the radius via the `inner sep` key.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,calc}
\NewDocumentCommand{\markpicA}{m}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=of pic cs:#1]{\mypicA};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\markpicB}{m}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=of pic cs:#1]{\mypicB};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypicA}{}{\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={anchor=center}]
\node[circle,fill] at (0,0) {};% circle does not options, so "3pt" can be dropped
\draw[] (-.5,-.5) -- (.5,-.5);
\node[circle,fill] at (0,-1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mypicB}{}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[radius=3pt]  (0,0) circle; 
    \draw[] (-.5,-.5) -- (.5,-.5);
    \fill[radius=3pt]  (0,-1) circle; 
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
\begin{document}

The diagram \tikzmark{C} above is now correct.
\markpicA{C}
\bigskip

The diagram below is correct.
\bigskip


\mypicA


\vspace{4em}

The diagram \tikzmark{D} above is now correct.
\markpicB{D}
\bigskip

The diagram below is correct.
\bigskip


\mypicB

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the problem. This is very simplified code from a package, so ideally I'd like a way to "insulate" my command and allow its use like this without a savebox.

Comment: @AlanMunn This can also help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture

Comment: @AlanMunn You can avoid the misplacement of the circle nodes by setting their anchor to be `center`. The problem is that in the ambient `tikzpicture` you use the `above` key, which sets the `anchor` to `south`, so you need to undo this. I added a code for this scenario. There can be other "offending" keys which you may have to undo in a similar fashion in variations of this scenario.

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem nicely. In general the code will not be embedded in another `tikzpicture` except in this particular `tikzmark` case, so I'll take my chances on embedding by adding the `nodes={anchor=center}` to my picture style. The `circle=3pt` is not actually used in my real code; not sure what I was thinking when I used it in the example.