# Nested labeled colored boxes with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, labels, nesting

I need nested boxes, as they are shown in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18600/expandable-nested-boxes-with-tikz), but colored ones.

I tried both solutions. Using `shapes.multipart` I totally failed when tried to generate the nodeparts by a `foreach` command. If I use multiple `\tikz` parts in one nodepart, I can use `foreach`, but I am unable to put them in one column (tried matrix and failed).

Trying [`drs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/drs) with `xcolor` I almost got a correct result, but when I write this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{drs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{green}
{
    \drs{box label}
        {
            drs box text
        }
}

\end{document}
```

some margin around the `drs` generated box is colored as well.

What I basically need is to draw a colored box with some label. Then, by a `foreach` loop, to generate several colored boxes inside it. It is perfectly possible to have them in one column.

Following advice from egreg I wrote this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\zcolorbox}[2]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\nestedbox}[3]{\zcolorbox{#1}{\drs{#2}{#3}}}

\usepackage{drs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\nestedbox{green}{box label}{\nestedbox{yellow}{inner box label}{inner box text}}

\end{document}
```

and got this:

[image: colored nested drs boxes with fboxsep set to 0]

How can I get rid of the yellow color there, but not of the space?

Comment: Can you post a *complete* minimal document with the code you've tried? Where is the `\drs` command from, for example?

Comment: Done. Should I post the multipart document as well? It would be maybe better with drs, as the syntax is *much* cleaner for what I need.

Comment: The presence of a margin around a box probably means that the dimension \fboxsep is non-zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I open a small discuss.

Here an approach using LaTeX3 in combination of some features defined in the kernel LaTeX2e.

The input of your colorbox is as follow:

```
\nestedbox[<options>]{<header>}{<inner box>}
```

where the `inner box` is a comma separated list.

The available options are:

- `outer-color` sets the background color of the whole box
- `inner-color` sets the background of the inner box
- `bgcolor` sets `inner-color` and `outer-color`
- `line-color` sets the color of the frame`
- `margin` adds extra space to the widest word
- `alignment` choose the alignment of the boxes. Available are `left`, `right` and `center`
- `header-font` sets the font of the header
- `label-font` sets the font of the inner boxes

Here the complete code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { colorbox }
  {
    outer-color  .tl_set:N   = \l_colorbox_outercolor_tl,
    inner-color  .tl_set:N   = \l_colorbox_innercolor_tl,
    line-color    .tl_set:N   = \l_colorbox_linecolor_tl,
    bgcolor       .meta:n    = { outer-color = #1 , inner-color = #1 },
    margin       .dim_set:N = \l_colorbox_margin_dim,
  }
\keys_set:nn { colorbox } { bgcolor = white , line-color = black , margin = 20pt }

\tl_new:N  \l_colorbox_left_align_tl 
\tl_new:N  \l_colorbox_right_align_tl
\keys_define:nn { colorbox }
 {
  alignment .choice:,
  alignment / left   .code:n = {
                                             \tl_set:Nn  \l_colorbox_left_align_tl {\null} 
                                             \tl_set:Nn  \l_colorbox_right_align_tl {\hfill}
                                            },
  alignment / right .code:n = {
                                             \tl_set:Nn  \l_colorbox_left_align_tl {\hfill} 
                                             \tl_set:Nn  \l_colorbox_right_align_tl {\null}
                                            },
  alignment / center .code:n = {
                                             \tl_set:Nn  \l_colorbox_left_align_tl {\hfill} 
                                             \tl_set:Nn  \l_colorbox_right_align_tl {\hfill}
                                            },
 }
\keys_set:nn { colorbox } { alignment = center }

\keys_define:nn { colorbox }
  {
    header-font .tl_set:N   = \l_colorbox_headerfont_tl,
    label-font    .tl_set:N   = \l_colorbox_labelfont_tl,
  }
\keys_set:nn { colorbox } { header-font = \bfseries , label-font=\normalfont }
%#1 = options
%#2 = top label
%#3 = inner boxes clist
\clist_new:N \l_colorbox_innerbox_clist
\tl_new:N     \l_colorbox_boxlabel_tl
\dim_new:N \l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim
\NewDocumentCommand \nestedbox { O{} m m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { colorbox } {#1}
  \tl_set:Nn      \l_colorbox_boxlabel_tl     { #2 }
  \clist_set:Nn  \l_colorbox_innerbox_clist { #3 }
  \clist_if_empty:NTF \l_colorbox_innerbox_clist
    {
      \fcolorbox { \l_colorbox_linecolor_tl   }
                     { \l_colorbox_outercolor_tl }
                     { \tl_use:N  \l_colorbox_boxlabel_tl }
     }   
    {
       \colorbox_find_widthest_label:NN \l_colorbox_boxlabel_tl \l_colorbox_innerbox_clist
       \colorbox_output_inner_label:NN  \l_colorbox_boxlabel_tl \l_colorbox_innerbox_clist
    }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \colorbox_find_widthest_label:NN #1#2
 {
   \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \tl_use:N #1}
   \dim_set:Nn   \l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
   \clist_map_inline:Nn #2
    {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { ##1 }
      \dim_compare:nNnT 
         { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } > { \l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim }
         {  \dim_set:Nn   \l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } }
    }
%    \dim_use:N \l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim
  }

\cs_new:Npn \colorbox_output_inner_label:NN #1#2
 {
   \fcolorbox { \l_colorbox_linecolor_tl   }
                  { \l_colorbox_outercolor_tl }
                  { 
                    \begin{minipage}
                         {\dim_eval:w      \l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim 
                                              +  \l_colorbox_margin_dim  
                                              +  2\fboxsep +2\fboxrule
                           \dim_eval_end: }
                        \centering %\offinterlineskip
                        \hbox_to_wd:nn 
                            {\l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim +  \l_colorbox_margin_dim } 
                            {
                              \l_colorbox_left_align_tl
                              \l_colorbox_headerfont_tl
                              \strut \tl_use:N  #1
                              \l_colorbox_right_align_tl
                             }  
                        \tex_vrule:D width \linewidth height 0pt \scan_stop:
                        \clist_map_inline:Nn #2 
                         { \\\nointerlineskip
                              \fcolorbox 
                                              { \l_colorbox_innercolor_tl }
                                              { \l_colorbox_innercolor_tl }
                                              { \hbox_to_wd:nn 
                                                        {\l_colorbox_widthest_label_dim +  \l_colorbox_margin_dim } 
                                                        {
                                                         \l_colorbox_left_align_tl 
                                                          \l_colorbox_labelfont_tl
                                                          \strut ##1  
                                                          \l_colorbox_right_align_tl
                                                         } 
                                               }
                         }
                     \end{minipage}    
                   }                                                  
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\nestedbox{box label}{inner,foo, long long long text}

\nestedbox[inner-color=yellow,outer-color=green]{box label}{inner,foo, long long long text}

\nestedbox[inner-color=red!20,alignment=left,label-font=\itshape]{box label}{inner,foo, long long long text}
\end{document}
```

In the final pdf I have no lines between the inner boxes.

[image]

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. Can you please change the default bgcolor to white, remove the lines around inner boxes and add the option for alignment?

Comment: I see the bgcolor *is* white, my mistake

Comment: @Dadam: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Your code produces the expected result. You have to recall that TeX is a typesetting engine, so spaces are in general *not* ignored as is the case for most programming languages. End-of-line characters are equivalent to spaces (unless there are two in a row, generating an end-of-paragraph command).

End-of-lines can be masked by `%` characters, so a first adjustment for you code is

```
\colorbox{green}
{%
    \drs{box label}
        {%
            drs box text%
        }%
}
```

(Note that spaces at the beginning of a line *are* ignored, to allow code indentation.) A better way to write this code might be

```
\colorbox{green}{%
  \drs{box label}
      {drs box text}%
  }
```

This doesn't cope with another small problem: `\colorbox` surrounds the box contents with some padding (which in general is what's desired). The padding is `\fboxsep` wide on all four margins. Thus one can do

```
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{green}{%
   \drs{box label}
      {drs box text}%
  }}
```

and the extra braces will ensure that the setting of `\fboxsep` will not propagate and be confined in the group.

One can take advantage of TeX and define a command for this:

```
\newcommand{\zcolorbox}[2]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
```

and use

```
\zcolorbox{green}{%
  \drs{box label}
      {drs box text}%
  }
```

which finally gives the desired result.

[image]

For what concerns nesting of colored `\drs` boxes, the problem lies in the implementation of `drs`, that keeps into account the nesting level, in order to add a suitable padding above and below the inner box: this is the cause of the yellow stripes you're experimenting.

A hack is to define the inner box beforehand:

```
\usepackage{drs}
\usepackage{xcolor,array}
\newcommand{\zcolorbox}[2]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\nestedbox}[3]{\zcolorbox{#1}{\drs{#2}{#3}}}

\newsavebox{\drsboxA}
\newcommand{\innerdrs}[3]{%
  \sbox{\drsboxA}{\zcolorbox{#1}{\drs{#2}{#3}}}%
  \ht\drsboxA=\dimexpr\ht\drsboxA+2pt\relax
  \dp\drsboxA=\dimexpr\dp\drsboxA+2pt\relax}

\begin{document}


\innerdrs{yellow}{inner box label}{inner box text}
\nestedbox{green}{box label}{\usebox\drsboxA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working correctly for the nested box, I edited my question.